# Выбрать уникальные значения и посчитать количество

Tags: python, list, numpy

Есть 2d спискок, количество элементов в списке равно количестве списков, например:

```
[[12, 0, 6], [12, 12, 5], [20, 30, 0]]
```

Желаемый результат:

```
12: 3

0: 2

6: 1

5: 1

20: 1

30: 1
```

(Выбрать уникальные значения и посчитать количество )

Максимально быстрым способом при необходимости использовать numpy

Comment: А какие структуры данных вам известны в Python?

Comment: Не совсем понял при чем другие структуры данных, так как в коде используется только список(list)

Comment: Для "быстро посчитать". Впрочем, уже ответили

Answer (score 5):

```py
from collections import Counter

a = [[12, 0, 6], [12, 12, 5], [20, 30, 0]]

for r in Counter(x for y in a for x in y).items():
    print(*r, sep=': ')
```

```
12: 3
0: 2
6: 1
5: 1
20: 1
30: 1
```

Comment: counter'у можно отдать генератор `Counter(x for y in a for x in y)`

Answer (score 1):

поскольку стоит тег numpy

```
a = numpy.array([[12, 0, 6], [12, 12, 5], [20, 30, 0]])
res = dict(zip(*numpy.unique(a, return_counts=True)))
```

но порядок ключей в результате будет другой

```
{0: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 12: 3, 20: 1, 30: 1}
```

Comment: Думаю, на больших объемах быстрее будет: count, value=np.histogram(a, bins=np.unique(a))